# How do I disable maven build when using Maven 2.0 integration for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, build, preferences, m2eclipse

How do I stop the "Maven 2.0 integration" plugin from running maven build, while keeping "build automatically" checked?

I'm pretty sure it used to be some check box to disable maven build before, but after upgrading Ubuntu; eclipse seems to have been updated in the process, and now I cannot find any way to turn off the maven build. The maven build takes literally minutes (about 5 minutes or so), while just running java build used to finish in seconds.

Is it no longer possible to disable it or have they just hidden it well?

If it's not possible, will eclipse be able to compile my maven project without the plugin?

(Trying to google for a solution the closes I got to an answer was several archives of [this old post](http://old.nabble.com/Can-automatic-build-be-turned-off--td23750237.html) where the answer essentially were "You should be able to disable Maven builder in project preferences..." which doesn't really help because I cannot find any on/off settings there)

Comment: A slow build wouldn't be so annoying if Eclipse did not block and pop an "waiting to complete" etc. dialog if I try to save again before the autobuild has completed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the Maven Project Builder, **right-click** on your project then **Preferences > Builders** and uncheck the **Maven Project Builder** (you cannot modify the default maven builder).

[alt text http://www.imagebanana.com/img/fikqaidv/screenshot_010.png](http://www.imagebanana.com/img/fikqaidv/screenshot_010.png)

If this removes "too much" things, you can maybe create your own custom Maven builder. Click **New**, select **Maven Build** and configure it as you want.

[alt text http://www.imagebanana.com/img/rwkmm7jb/screenshot_010.png](http://www.imagebanana.com/img/rwkmm7jb/screenshot_010.png)

---

> Disabling it seems to stop eclipse from knowing about the related projects causing the java build to fail. Is there a some sort of dummy, no-operation goal I can use for auto build goals?

I guess you would have to add the related projects in the **Project References** (or to uncheck **Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects**).

> Is there a way to disable it for all 6 related projects in the workspace simultaneously?

I don't think so.

---

At the end, all this tweaks looks like ugly hacks. If you're not satisfied by the m2eclipse plugin, maybe you should use the `maven-eclipse-plugin` instead (i.e. run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`) instead to generate the `.project` and `.classpath` files and import your projects as **Existing Project** into Eclipse.

Comment: Disabling it seems to stop eclipse from knowing about the related projects causing the java build to fail. Is there a some sort of dummy, no-operation goal I can use for auto build goals?

Comment: Is there a way to disable it for all 6 related projects in the workspace simultaneously?