# How to use custom lifecycle for m2eclipse-type project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration, m2eclipse, lifecycle

When using **m2eclipse** ... if you **right-click on a maven project** and select **Properties** from the popup menu, you enter the project preferences dialog, which has a **Maven->Lifecycle** section allowing to customize which **build phases** should be bound to the build lifecycle, whenever the project is **refreshed or clean-built**. However, these customizations are coarse-grained and get lost upon "project-configuration-update" (same, if you put file "org.maven.ide.eclipse.prefs", where these settings are saved under version control ... upon project import, the file will be overwritten).

Searching for a solution, I found [this answer from pascal-thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865803/how-do-i-disable-maven-build-when-using-maven-2-0-integration-for-eclipse/2865855#2865855) where he describes "how to create a new Maven builder in project preferences..." which didn't quite help in my case, because the "Create-New-Builder-Dialog" in my Eclipse setup unfortunately **cannot find such a Maven Builder**. And the existing builder has the "Edit-Builder" button disabled.

Comment: Found, that the new-builder-dialog as mentioned by Pascal, is created with a call to org.eclipse.m2e.ui.internal.launch.MavenBuilderConfigurationTabGroup.createTabs(ILaunchConfigurationDialog, String) - however do not know, how I can teach Eclipse to have it available in the project properties' builder preference...

Answer (score 0):

With Maven all build information is stored inside pom.xml and most detailed configuration is [maven plugin configuration](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html).

All configuration inside Eclipse IDE should be done using [m2e Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). Well, I don't know where to find all possible configuration. But sometime some option are available as Eclipse warning while editing pom.xml

Here is example of my current settings. It generated by m2e.

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        wro4j-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.4.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>jshint</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.github.searls
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        jasmine-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.2.0.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            generateManualRunner
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```