# Skip validation and maven build on startup in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

Technically I'm using Springsource Toolsuite, but I think this is a general eclipse question. My eclipse startup is now in the minutes, because on startup its running Maven Builder: FULL_BUILD and validation over all the open projects. I recently started working with a very large application, and going through the build and validation takes forever.

Is there a way to skip this at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off automatic build under the Project top-level menu. Then you can explicitly control when to kick off a build. I would also ping m2eclipse guys on their forum about this issue. It sounds like there is a malfunction in their builder. It should not kick off a full build on every startup unless you workspace is significantly changed since the last Eclipse session.

Comment: is this what you're suggesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865803/how-do-i-disable-maven-build-when-using-maven-2-0-integration-for-eclipse

Comment: No. My suggestion has a different effect. Instead of disabling maven builder, turning off automatic build gives you control of when the build is to be run. If you happy to turn off maven builder completely, then the solution you've referenced is the right way to go.

Comment: no, i'd like to just gain control when the build is run, but I don't see where in the "Project top-level menu" is this option?

Comment: "Project top-level menu" means look at the top of Eclipse window and find the menu labeled Project.